# How to show the average x-coordinates of four collinear points on the curve is a constant?

Tags: geometry, problem-solving

> Show that if four distinct points of the curve $y=2x^4+7x^3+3x-5$ are collinear then their average x-coordinate is some constant k. Find k.

Shall I use vector to calculate their x-coordinate, or shall I use coordinate geometry? I always find geometry of this type challenging, could someone give me some advice on how to improve my ability on that?

Comment: Nice problem where's it from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calculation of the $x$-coordinates is a distraction posed by the question writer. Collinear points are determined by the intersection of the polynomial and some line $y=mx+b$. Subtracting the equations gives us a new polynomial whose roots are exactly the $x$-coordinates of interest. The average is just the sum divided by 4, and the sum is attainable with Vieta's formulas as $-7/2$ (the higher degree terms don't change in the subtraction). Hence the average is always $-7/8$.

---

If you're unfamiliar with Vieta's formulas, you can observe that every fourth degree polynomial has 4 roots, so it can be written as
$$\alpha(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d) = \alpha x^4 - \alpha (a+b+c+d)x^3 + \ldots.$$
Dividing the coefficients of the two highest power terms gives you the negative of the sum of the roots.

Comment: Now I feel myself a bit stupid, how did you get this method?This is a sample interview question.

Comment: My thought process was as follows: 1) Let's graph it 2) Too complicated to do that 3) If I pick 4 points then determine the line, maybe that will help 4)  Wait, let me do that backwards. FIRST let's pick the line so that we can guarantee the points are collinear 5) Determining intersections is hard, but we are looking for an average 6) Average is determined by a sum, and sum of roots is easy to calculate

Comment: Interview for what? What an interesting question to be asked for an interview.